# Why C++ allows returning ifstream object?

Tags: c++, c++11, fstream, xvalue

In C++98, the following code does not compile because the ifstream has no copy constructor:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

ifstream f() {
    return ifstream("main.cpp");
}

int main() {
    ifstream st= f();
}
```

However using multiple GCC versions with C++11, this compiles without warnings. What is the reason of this?

Comment: Verified: [https://ideone.com/NpWsRU](https://ideone.com/NpWsRU)

Comment: RVO / copy elision : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization

Comment: @HattedRooster: Guaranteed RVO is a C++17 thing, not C++11 as in this question.

Comment: @HattedRooster Copy/move constructors are still needed in C++11 when RVO is applied. This is caused by additional move constructor, which did not exist in C++98.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/3s9eGhTh8

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++11 added move constructors. The stream is now moved. The source object here is a temporary in the return expression, which can be moved to the `st` object in `main`.